# Limitation on large in filter for spark

Tags: apache-spark

What is the limitation for large in filter in spark

```
spark.sql("select * from tableA where a in (select id from table_b)")
```

Does spark make each executor download a copy of `(select id from table_b")` , what happens if `(select id from table_b")` cannot fit into executor

Is spark smart enough to split the task and do a join after?

Split `(select id from table_b")` into N executors
Have each row goes through each executors once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask spark to tell you with

`spark.sql("select * from tableA where a in (select id from table_b)").explain("formatted")`

You'll probably see something like this

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (14)
+- HashAggregate (13)
   +- Exchange (12)
      +- HashAggregate (11)
         +- Project (10)
            +- SortMergeJoin LeftSemi (9)
               :- Sort (3)
               :  +- Exchange (2)
               :     +- Scan parquet table_a (1)
               +- Sort (8)
                  +- Exchange (7)
                     +- Project (6)
                        +- Filter (5)
                           +- Scan parquet table_b (4)
```

The Exchange operators mean that *both* tables are shuffled by ID across the executors, so that each executor can perform the join locally.